# Is there a good way to load tiny_mce_popup.js through editor.windowManager.open?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, tinymce

I need to load tiny_mce_popup.js in my page video.php. The page video.php is a popup.

```
 {text:'Video', onclick: function() {

        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'TinyMCE',
            url: url + '/video.php',
            width: 700,
            height: 700,
            buttons: [{
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
            }]
        });

    }},
```

i want to avoid a hardcoded path like

```
 <script src="../../../../../wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
```

inside video.php.
have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use more appropriate path, like:

```
$path = ABSPATH . WPINC . '/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js'
```

And you should use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), so you could put something like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-tinymce-popup', $path);
```